# How can I improve this Swift readLine code?

Tags: swift, input, console-application

It works, but I don't think is good enough.  Is it possible to use readLine() outside an if-let construct??? I just find the scope very limiting and do not believe I can pass arguments using this from the command line using this method.  Can anyone suggest a better approach to this issue?

```
    import Foundation

    print("\nTemperature Conversion\n")
    print("What is your current Temperature Unit?\n ")
    print("Valid options are f or F for Fahrenheit, c or C for Celsius: \n")

    if var  temp = readLine() {
        switch temp{
        case "c","C":
            print("And the temperature: ")
            if var  degrees = readLine() {
                var fahr = (5 * Float(degrees)! * 1.8 + 32)
                print("\(degrees) Degrees is equal to \(fahr) degrees Fahrenheit. \n")
            } else {
                print("You entered an invalid temperature")
            }
        case "f","F":
            print("Fahrenheit")
            if var degrees = readLine() {
                var celsius = (5 * Float(degrees)! - 32) / 9;
                print("\(degrees) Degrees is equal to \(celsius) degrees Fahrenheit. \n")
            } else {
                print("You entered an invalid temperature")
            }
        default:
            print("Not a valid Temperature unit")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`readLine()` returns a `String?`, which is `nil` if there is no more input (EOF which is CTRL-D in Xcode). You need to unwrap it somehow and the `if let` statement is perfect for that.

Arguments have nothing to do with standard input (`readLine()`), you can get the arguments like this instead:

```
Process.arguments // type [String]
```